# Does polenta freeze well?

Tags: storage-method, freezing, polenta

Does freezing polenta substantially change its consistency? I like polenta but would prefer to make it in batches instead of every time I want to eat it.  After I make it, I usually let it cool, cut it into shapes, and then pan-fry it.

Comment: Looking forward to other people's answers on this one. I've had some negative results, but I also think I've left it in the freezer *too* long, like many months.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want to pop frozen slices into a frying pan? That should work just fine. The slicing allows for quick freezing, which decreases the size of water crystals and the effect they have on food. And quick frying keeps the disturbance of the polenta to a minimum.

In general, basic polenta should be fine, since starch, the many component to consider, responds alright to freezing. Recipes with cream make things more complicated. Freezing and reheating cream can lead to separation, so reheating a big block in a pan could leave you with pools of oil.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [polenta freezes very well](http://askville.amazon.com/made-polenta-time-great-frozen/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=24857357) for up to 3 months.  It sounds like you need to make sure it cools to room temperature first, and as with everything you put in the freezer, make sure it's tightly wrapped.

Comment: Askville, Yahoo! Answers, and their ilk are of questionable quality and reliability.

Comment: I normally agree, but the first answers I found were from ChowHound, so I tend to think the answers are fairly accurate. http://goo.gl/0oxP

Comment: I'm thinking the Polenta with Braised Meatballs sold under the Top Chef name by Schwan's is also probably a good indication.

http://www.homecookingmemories.com/2010/02/top-chef-frozen-meal-polenta-with.html

Comment: In my student days I used to buy frozen polenta.

Answer (score 0):

Scarpone Brand Polenta roll says specifically not to freeze

Answer (score 0):

Yes the tube polenta says not to freeze but thy mean do not freeze while still in the package. I have frozen slices before and they are fine.